# Is there a way to measure the magnetic field of a digital device and mask it?

Tags: electromagnetic

I was reading this report: https://www.fanaticalfuturist.com/2018/05/hackers-find-a-way-to-neutralise-faraday-cages-to-exploit-air-gapped-systems/

It says how researchers used magnetic field generated by CPU to exfiltrate data from an air gapped system. They proposed few solutions to protect against such attacks, two of them were impractical, one solution seems feasible, it requires masking the magnetic field generated by the CPU with a stronger magnetic field from something else.

Is there a way to measure how much magnetic field is generated by a CPU and what everyday objects generate more magnetic field than CPU, which I can use to mask the CPU's magnetic field?

Comment: Sure, with a magnetic field meter.

Answer (score 1):

First up what they are actually measuring, this is mainly the DC current change in the power supply to the CPU, vs the CPU itself, as the CPU will have so many opposing field orientations internally, it is likely to cancel most of it,

Your looking for the highest current, in this case for a high end CPU, you might have 100+ Amps flowing through the motherboard, now this again should mostly cancel, but due to multiple grounds will couple some ratio of current through effectively 1 turn of wire, out of the power supply, down 1 loom, across the motherboard, and some ground current back to the power supply via other looms, its highly specific, so the exact magnitude of the signal would be hard to define.

For measuring it, the researches seemed to be using a phone magnetometer to listen to variations within a few Hz, you can attempt a similar effect

What everyday objects generate more magnetic field? that would be an electromagnet. in this exact example, it would be something with a wide frequency spread and random amplitude variations, but it would likely need to be some active circuitry as its the change in magnetic field that you need to make it very hard to recover,

I suspect the amplitudes they are working with are similar to earths magnetic field for the phone to be a viable method, as such you can use something like a Merritt coil arrangement in your Faraday cage, and drive it to constantly shift between random orientations at random speeds.

Edit: To expand a little, there are limits to how fast a phone magnetometer can sample (Datasheet), using this you can constrain the exact frequency range you need to cover, to make your jamming even more effective, the minimum is constrained slightly by practicality, the magnetic feild needs to change enough for the phone to recover it over the noise, so I expect it would not be a gentle ramp of current, but a 0-100% situation, so higher frequency content will likely be where jamming will hurt the most.

Comment: Actually the link I gave, list two ways to achieve this, the one you are talking about using smartphone is called Magneto, the other one called the Odini. I don't see anything mentioned about the DC current change in the PSU to CPU mentioned in the article. The research papers are behind a paywall. The article just mentions load to the CPU, it could be any kind of load.

Comment: I could not read the article in full either. However there are only so many things in a pc that can cause a low frequency magnetic feild that could possibly be detected from a few meters away. As such i expect it to be similar to amplitude modulation. Otherwise small background tasks would not interfere with it.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually its own branch of electrical engineering. First though, if you’re trying to just measure dc magnetic fields you do get an instrument called a magnetometer that’s can measure the strength of a magnetic field.

But a much more common problem in electrical engineering is measuring and dealing with the electromagnetic radiation that’s emitted by electrical equipment. Essentially, any electric circuit can act as an antenna ie it will emit electromagnetic radiation. This is especially a problem for high voltage and high frequency circuits. There are special devices that can measure this such as an EMF meter. Before most electrical appliances/equipment is released on the market it has to be electromagnetic compliant, which pretty much means if you use the appliance, it won’t destroy other equipment (phones, computers, etc) around it from the electromagnetic radiation

Comment: Thanks. If every electric circuit can act as an antenna, a CPU, GPU and motherboard must be filled with antennas, can their electrical activity be used to steal or spy on a person's activity at their computer?